# Is it possible to resize the Preview window to make it smaller?

Tags: macos, preview

Looks like similar questions have been asked previously with no answer. Trying again.  Attached is an example of what I view for research.  Id like to be able to make smaller the area of the window so that the edges are closer to the subject picture.  Is it possible with Preview?  If not, any suggestions as to another viewer to use that would allow a closer cropped window?
Im on a MacBook Pro, Monterrey 12.6.3.

[image: Preview default view]

Comment: Tried bettersnaptool app...  Didnt do it - could make the window bigger and move, but not smaller.

Comment: Preview opens, by default at 100%.  If the image has padding which it appears yours does, then it will appear that Preview is opening larger than your image.

Comment: It’s the same as above with any image I open. I cannot get the grey Preview area closer to images. I’m told it’s a characteristic of Preview.